# Scalaz: sequence of disjuntions to the disjunction of sequence

Tags: list, scala, scalaz

I am trying to transform `List[\/[String, Int]]` to `\/[String, List[Int]]`.
All solutions that I was able to find point out to the usage of `sequenceU`. 
I was not able to return `\/[String, List[Int]]`, since sequenceU returns type `G.M[List[G.A]]`:

```
def f(x: Int): \/[String, Int] = if (x > 0) x.right[String] else "failure".left[Int]
val result: G.M[List[G.A]] = List(3, 4, 5).map(f).sequenceU
```

What am I doing wrong with `sequenceU`? How it should be used to get `\/[String, List[Int]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the type ascription:

```
scala> val result = List(3, 4, 5).map(f).sequenceU
result: scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = \/-(List(3, 4, 5))
```